# OnPress Issue on TouchabeOpacity

Tags: react-native

**Question:** I created TouchabelOpacity Component and want to alert message when tap it.

```
<Image style={styles.item} source={props.source} >
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={props.onDelete(props.index)} >
                    <Image style={styles.closeButton} source={require('../../Images/DashImages/closeButton.png')} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Image>
```

And onPress function is like that

```
onPress = (index) => {
alert(index);
}
```

But when run the code, it alerts automatically when it rendered. I didn't tap, but alerts automatically.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wrap it with function this to prevent immediate run

```
<Image style={styles.item} source={props.source} >
            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => props.onDelete(props.index)} >
                <Image style={styles.closeButton} source={require('../../Images/DashImages/closeButton.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Image>
```

Comment: This answer is very useful help for me. I want to say thank you.